# Microsoft JScript runtime error: Member not found

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, jquery, partial-views, jquery-dialog

i am using asp.net mvc3 and jquery dialogue to open partial view in main view

here is my structure..

**partialview 1**

```
<input type="button" onclick="function1();">
```

**partial view 2**

```
<form method="post"> 
    //some elements

    @Html.RenderPartial("partialview1");
</form>
```

**view 1**

```
<script src="myscript.js" />
<script src="jquery.js"/> 
//some element

<div>
    load partialview 2 as jquery dialogue 
</div>
```

**myscript.js**

```
  function function1()
  {
     //some code
  }
```

this is just only overview of my application

now in above structure if i click on button in the **partialview1** i am getting this error **: Microsoft JScript runtime error: Member not found.**

Comment: Problem is probably inside `function1`, could you post what "some code" actually is?

Comment: actually function1 is not called.. as i have put debugger at first line.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

I found the solution in my case.

```
<input id="function1" type="button" onclick="function1();">
```

I have used `id` of the input type button (**ie:** `function1`)  as the same name of function (**ie:** `function1`).

As I don't know much about it. But by changing `id` of the button or function name solves my problem.

Comment: That makes sense. Internet Explorer has the bad habit of creating global variables for elements' IDs, overwriting existing variables and functions.

Comment: I had a javascript function with the same name as a hidden field. Changing that stopped this error.

Answer (score 1):

Actually, 'Member Not Found' occurs on all browsers and other non-browser programs. In browsers, placing a button or radial with the same name as the function it calls within a form induces this error. Either rename the button or move it outside of the form.