# Hiding placeholder Div, then using same code on another page giving javascript error

Tags: javascript, html, ajax, asp.net-mvc-4

I have code that is generated by passing data from an ajax call to an `ActionView` method in my controller. I can only access that data when the ajax call returns. The area where I am trying to display my data is not getting refreshed so I added it to my `PartialView` to return back to the page div I created. My issue is that I have a placeholder of exactly the same small table so that the page does not look goofy before the user submits what they need to to call the ajax request. My issue is that the button I have in the placeholder area and area that I have displaying back are not working correctly. I think what is happening is that the javascript is getting confused by the two areas having the same information, but changing the names/ids doesn't seem to fix it. Here is my code. (I also need the placeholder table to be functional before it is hidden)

This is in the main page:

```
        <tr>
            <td>Comments: @Html.TextBox("comments2", comment)</td>
            <td></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>

            <td style="vertical-align: middle;">Booking#:@Html.TextBox("bookNum2", bookNum)</td>

            <td><input id="saveOrder2" type="button" value="Save Order2" onclick="saveOrder2(true)" /></td>

        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td style="vertical-align: middle;">Ship Date:@Html.TextBox("shipDate2", shipDate)</td>
            <td>
                <input id="Build" type="button" value="Build Load" /> </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
```

In the PartialView page I have this:

```
        <tr>
            <td>Comments: @Html.TextBox("comments", comment)</td>
            <td></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>

            <td style="vertical-align: middle;">Booking#:@Html.TextBox("bookNum", bookNum)</td>

            <td><input id="saveOrder" type="button" value="Save Order" onclick="saveOrder(true)" /></td>

        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td style="vertical-align: middle;">Ship Date:@Html.TextBox("shipDate", shipDate)</td>
            <td>
                <input id="Build" type="button" value="Build Load" /></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
```

Then the javascript function I am using:

```
 function saveOrder(isSave)
{
    var comments = document.getElementById("comments2").value;
    var bookNum = document.getElementById("bookNum2").value;
    var shipDate = document.getElementById("shipDate2").value;


    var itemList = grabSaveItems();
    //alert(itemList.toString());
    var request = $.ajax(
         {
             type: "POST",
             url: "/Home/saveOrder",
             data: "itemList=" + itemList+"&isSave="+isSave+"&comments="+comments+"&bookNum="+bookNum+"&shipDate="+shipDate,
             success: function (itemList) {
             }
         });
    request.done(function () {
        if (isSave == true)
        {
            alert("The Order Was Saved");
        }

    });

    request.fail(function (Check, textStatus) { alert("Request failed: " + textStatus); });
}
```

So based on the order number I add the information I need to the Model and then return my PartialView to display what I need.
When I click Save Order after this ajax call is made I get the following runtime error:
Microsoft JScript runtime error: Member not found. Which occurs just after the call to save Order, the debugger points to the line just after this function, not sure what that means. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I knew it was something dumb. It looks like Javascript gets freaky when you assign the id of the input the same name as your function so it doesn't know what to do/call.

```
<td><input id="**saveOrder"** type="button" value="Save Order" onclick="**saveOrder**(true)"/></td>
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13647631/microsoft-jscript-runtime-error-member-not-found